# Why is a new model created on Azure Analysis Services when I open the project file in Visual Studio?

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I am new to creating tabular models with Azure Analysis Services and can't figure out why, when I download the Visual Studio model and open it on my local machine, it triggers a script on AS and uploads a new version despite no changes?

I get an alert window saying: 
"Opening this file in the Tabular Model Designer causes a script to be executed on an Analysis Services server. Do not open this file in the Tabular Model Designer unless you trust the source of this file. Do you want to continue opening this file?"

Here are the exact steps I took:

- Downloaded a new version of the Visual Studio file from AAS.
- Unzipped and loaded into VS.
- Connected to the workspace server for the model.
- Double clicked on the model file.
- Logged into my Azure workplace account from the pop up window.
- Alert window appears.

Any help on why this is happening is appreciated, as I am even unsure where to look and online searches are not providing results. Another point to note is that this only happens for me, not my colleague.

Any tips on removing the new versions from AAS would be great as this is for a client and I can't leave them sitting there...

Screenshot of models in Azure Analysis Services:

[image]

Comment: Okay so I am unsure why, but the unintentional new versions are temporary models that are supposed to live for the life of a session but somehow stayed for me. I didn't know that connecting to the Analysis Services through SQL Server Management Studio would allow you to delete these models. Problem solved.